# Can 'api_site_parameter' be added to related_site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, sites, related

It would be great if the [`related_site`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/related-site) type contained `api_site_parameter`. I realize that you probably don't want to clutter up `related_site` with a lot of unnecessary fields, but I think it makes sense to include `api_site_parameter` since it provides an easy way for an app to jump to a site's meta - the only information that is currently provided is the site name, URL (not too helpful to an app), and the relation to the parent.

Comment: Surely it would be better just to make related_site have jut two fields, `relation` and `site`. Where `site` is just a normal site type. Then use filters to choose what you want.

Comment: Even better is to have a `context` field, and have it not only on this route, but things like badge awards as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was added in the last deploy.

Originally I was planning for consumers to maintain the site cache based on host names, but I suppose it's better to have the "query with this" parameter readily available regardless of how a site is discovered.

Comment: Well - `api_site_parameter` seems like the best option for a key in a database anyway.